# org.scala-xml _2.12.4 ;1.0.6 not found

Tags: scala, sbt, gatling

I get "**Unresolved Dependencies" warning and "org.scala-lang.modules#scala-xml _2.12.4;1.0.6:**" not found when I am trying the compile the sbt project. Does anyone know the reason for this error?

**build.sbt**

```
enablePlugins(GatlingPlugin)

scalaVersion := "2.12.4"

ivyScala := ivyScala.value map { _.copy(overrideScalaVersion = true) }

scalacOptions := Seq(
 "-encoding", "UTF-8", "-target:jvm-1.8", "-deprecation",
 "-feature", "-unchecked", "-language:implicitConversions")

javaOptions in Gatling := overrideDefaultJavaOptions(
"-Xms1G",
"-Xmx2G",
"-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
 "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" % "jackson-module-scala_2.11" % "2.8.2",
 "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % "scalaVersion.value",
 "org.scala-lang.modules" % "scala-xml _2.12.4" % "1.0.6",

"com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-sqs" % "1.10.19",
"com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-sts" % "1.10.19",
"com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-s3" % "1.10.19",
"com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-dynamodb" % "1.10.19",

"org.bouncycastle" % "bcpg-jdk15on" % "1.52",
"org.bouncycastle" % "bcprov-jdk15on" % "1.52",

"io.gatling.highcharts" % "gatling-charts-highcharts" % "2.3.0" % "test",
"io.gatling" % "gatling-test-framework" % "2.3.0" % "test",
"com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.2")
```

**Here's is the error**

```
Error:Error while importing SBT project:
...
[info] Resolving org.bouncycastle#bcprov-jdk15on;1.58 ...
[info] Resolving io.gatling#gatling-test-framework;2.3.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#test-interface;1.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.12.4 ...   
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.14.5 ...
[warn]     ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]     ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]     ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]     :: org.scala-lang.modules#scala-xml _2.12.4;1.0.6: not found
[warn]     ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  
[warn]     Note: Unresolved dependencies path: 
[warn]         org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml _2.12.4:1.0. 
[warn]           +- default:loadtest-gatling_2.12:0.1-SNAPSHOT
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last *:update' for the full output.
[error] (*:ssExtractDependencies) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency:
    org.scala-lang.modules#scala-xml _2.12.4;1.0.6: not found
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scala-
lang.modules#scala-xml _2.12.4;1.0.6: not found
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed 07-Mar-2018 12:04:37
```

**plugins.sbt**

```
 resolvers += Resolver.url("gatling", url("https://dl.bintray.com/content
/gatling/sbt-plugins/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
addSbtPlugin("io.gatling" % "gatling-sbt" % "2.2.2")
```

**build.properties**
    sbt.version=0.13.1

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You use this:

```
"org.scala-lang.modules" % "scala-xml_2.12" % "1.0.6",
```

This will do the needful, as you don't need to specify the exact scala version, just 2.12 will do.

Or use this

```
"org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-xml" % "1.0.6"
```

The %% will help you to download the dependency specific to your scala version.